# Input/Output error when reading from serial port in Unix

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

My configurations for the serial port is close to the one in this link :
[Serial-programming-HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html) in the non-canonical input mode. This is my code where the problem happens:

```
    char buffer;
    int received;

    while (true) {

        received = read(serial_com,
            &buffer,
            sizeof(buffer));


        if (received < 0) {
            
            perror("error reading") << endl;
            cout << "error no." << errno;
            //exit(1);
        }

        cout << buffer;
    }
```

After I read one character, sometimes it returns the read character, and other times it gives me this error:

```
error reading: Input/output error 
error no.5
```

This error occurs as soon as I run the program. How can I fix this?

I have also noticed that when I print the variable `received`, it first prints `0` and then prints `-1` and then it prints the error mentioned.

Comment: That guide that you cite has low-quality code.  For robust and portable code, study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  You need to provide more details: e.g. your hardware, and a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.  You question is unanswerable as is, and will attract mostly WAGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to read data faster, than it comes in - and if you try to read a character, when none is available, this is indeed an IO error.

You have a few possibilities:

- Use blocking mode (this will freeze the program at the `read()` call, until data is available
- use `select` to make sure you only try to read, if there is a character available
- use a paltform-specific mechanism (like `epoll`)
- Use a library (like `libev`) to abstract away these problems.

Comment: I have used this line for using blocking mode : `fcntl(serial_com, F_SETFL, 0);` but still gives me the same error

Comment: okay, I have used VMIN = 1 and VTIME = 0 for blocking, and it should wait till it reads a character right? but still it gives me that error

Comment: *"you try to read a character, when none is available, this is indeed an IO error"* -- Incorrect, the expected **errno** should be **EAGAIN**. Data from the serial port is fully buffered by the termios subsystem. See data-flow diagram in [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html)